# Changes in model class not reflecting in View

Tags: android, android-databinding

This is my model class. I have a variable currentUser. When I change the current user, the recyclerview list should refresh. But, currently the variable value is changing, but view is not refreshing.

```
  public class DashBoardViewModel extends BaseObservable {
        private Activity context;
        public static Enum currentUser = com.stampmemories.app.AppConstants.USER_ROLES.PROVIDER;
```

My Binding adapter is such:

```
 @BindingAdapter({"menu_recycler", "current_user"})
    public static void bindNavigationMenu(RecyclerView recyclerView, Activity context, Enum user) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ArrayList<DrawerModel.Drawer.Sub_menu> navMenuList = new ArrayList<>();
        NavMenuAdapter adapter = new NavMenuAdapter(context, navMenuList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (user == USER_ROLES.CUSTOMER)
            navMenuList.addAll(CommonFunction.getMenuList(context, false));
        else if (user == USER_ROLES.PROVIDER)
            navMenuList.addAll(CommonFunction.getMenuList(context, true));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change `currentUser`, you need to either call `notifyChange()` or `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.currentUser)`.  A good practice would be to wrap `currentUser` with a setter that would call one of those 2 methods (the former notifies that all properties on the `BaseObservable` have changed, the latter just that the one has).

Comment: Its not working. The value is changing but the recyclerview is not updating. I had bind the RV using the user value condition and passed arraylist as parameter which would be updated. But its not happening.

Comment: I made it using ObservableArrayList. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry; I hadn't read your bindingAdapter closely enough.  I kind of see what you are trying to do now (I assume NavMenuAdapter is your own class)?  It's puzzling that ObservableArrayList would have fixed it given that you aren't so much changing the contents of the array as you are placing a brand new adapter with a brand new array in the recyclerView whenever currentUser changes.

Comment: I just wanted to update the arraylist content when one of the RecyclerView item is clicked. But, whenever the item is clicked an Observable variable & ObservableArrayList is updated. Henceforth, binding adapter is called and brand new adapter and adapter is set. Anyother way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if your ultimate goal is simply to catch clicks on the items, I do that by setting a click listener on the itemView in the constructor of the viewHolder.  Otherwise, it sounds like you found something that works.